# Problema con el enrutado al ejecutar métodos de varios proyectos en una solucion en visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rutas

Tengo una solución con varios proyectos. Intento ejecutar la acción de un controlador de uno de ellas desde el inicial. Para ello creo una instancia de ese controlador en a para llamar a su método `Index`.

El problema es que busca el método desde la raiz del primer proyecto, no desde el otro donde está.
 Así la ruta que busca es `/localhost:xxxx/Home/proyecto2/Home/Index`

El error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   Se ha quitado el recurso que está buscando, se le ha cambiado el nombre o no está disponible en estos momentos.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: no lo mencionas, pro se trata de proyectos asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un proyecto define el `host` y el `puerto`, pero no es parte del routing de la url, cada proyecto cambiara el `xxxx` quedando algo como ser:

```
 http://localhost:IpProyecto2/Home/Index
```

[Información general sobre el enrutamiento de ASP.NET MVC (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Si necesitas separar funcionalidad podrias implementar `Areas`, entonces si tendras un unico `host` y ese `proyecto2` al cual haces refencia sera el Area que lo define

[Áreas en ASP.NET MVC – Una forma de organizar nuestras aplicaciones](https://diegobersano.com.ar/2015/01/05/areas-en-asp-net-mvc-una-forma-de-organizar-nuestras-aplicaciones/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]